# To show function is $C^1[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

How do I show that the function

$$  \psi(t) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \chi(t):=-C\ln\dfrac{q-t}{q} & \mbox{for}\; t \in [0,\tau],\\
       \pi(t):=\chi(\tau)+\chi'(\tau)(t-\tau) & \mbox{otherwise}
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$ is $C^1[0,1]$, where $\tau$ satisfies $$\chi'(\tau)=\dfrac{1-\chi(\tau)}{1-\tau},$$ $q\in(0,1)$ and $0<\tau< 1$.

Comment: $\tau \neq 1$ ?

Comment: You should try to prove it on $[0,\tau)$ and $(\tau,1]$ first, then check what's going on at $\tau$. It should be quite straightforward...

Comment: @MarcPalm, I edited it.

Comment: Actually, I think you first need to prove that $\tau<q$. Otherwise $\chi$ (and also $\psi$) is not defined at $q$. However, the form of $\chi$ should make sure that such a $\tau$ exists.